# Opacity becoming transparent in browser

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, opacity

I just stuck with the opacity issue again. I tried something like this:

```
 var hiddenSection = $('div.hidden');
 hiddenSection.show()
        .css({ 'display': 'block' })
        .css({ width: $(window).width() + 'px', height: $(window).height() + 'px' })
        .css({ top: ($(window).height() - hiddenSection.height()) / 2 + 'px',left: ($(window).width() - hiddenSection.width()) / 2 + 'px'})
        .css({ 'background-color': '#333333', 'filter': 'alpha(opacity=70)', 'opacity': '0.7' })
        //.css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(105,105,105,0.8)' })
        .appendTo('body');
```

This thing is working fine with IE8 but some how in Chrome, Firefox i am getting this result:

**Screenshot:**

[image]

It is completely become transparent but i don't want to make popup transparent.how can i crack this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply opacity to an element that opacity is reflected on all child elements. That's why your popup content is transparent too.

CSS3 colors are not supported in IE8 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors), otherwise rgba would work great for this example.

```
background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7); /* Red, Green, Blue, Alpha */
```

I suppose only the layer with color #333333 should be transparent? Move the comment box outside of that div and center it in the browser window. This way the opacity will not apply to the popup element.

Markup something like this:

```
<div class="hidden">
  <div class="comment-box">Comment box content</div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```